# Get difference between to dates php

Tags: php

It is giving "MessageA non well formed numeric value encountered"

```
 $date="2014-06-06 12:00:00";  
 date_diff(date('Y-m-d H:i:s',$date),date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to get difference

```
$date1="2014-06-06 12:00:00"; 
$date2 = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

echo $diff = abs(strtotime($date2) - strtotime($date1));
```

or with datetime

```
$datetime1 = new DateTime("2014-06-06 12:00:00");
$datetime2 = new DateTime("2014-06-06 12:00:00");
$difference = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
echo 'Difference: '.$difference->y.' years, ' 
                   .$difference->m.' months, ' 
                   .$difference->d.' days';

print_r($difference);
```